# Using comprehension lists for choosing items by index with duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to choose items from a list by another list of indices by looping over them and choosing them by index, but the result is missing duplicate items .

example.

```
X = [[1, 'a', 33], [2, 'a', 44], [3, 'bb', 56]] #sample data
indices = [1,1,1]        #index with duplicates
[ x[-1] for i,x in enumerate(X) if i in indices]
```

I expect

```
[[2, 'a', 44], [2, 'a', 44], [2, 'a', 44]]
```

but I get

```
[[2, 'a', 44]]
```

I tried normal loop instead of comprehnsion and it works. but doesnt work when I try to get part of the list inside. so I want

Answer (score 1):

You want to iterate `indices` in the comprehension and pick that element from `X`:

```
>>> X = [[1, 'a', 33], [2, 'a', 44], [3, 'bb', 56]]
>>> indices = [1,1,1]
>>> [X[i] for i in indices]
[[2, 'a', 44], [2, 'a', 44], [2, 'a', 44]]
```

In your case it do not work because you `i` will be `1` only once in the iteration with enumerate

Comment: You're right, I now realize how stupid I was. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 [mainL[x] for x in indices]
```

Output:

```
[[2, 'a', 44], [2, 'a', 44], [2, 'a', 44]]
```